# How to Achieve this kind of sliding bar with tooltip in react native in charts

Tags: react-native, graph, charts, react-native-svg-charts, react-native-charts-wrapper

Hi there I want to achieve this kind of sliding line with tooltip in react native charts or SVG charts.Can anyone help me to figure it out how we can achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts-examples/blob/master/storybook/stories/interactive-chart/index.js) is example for interactive charts

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31237091)

Answer (score 1):

This type of chart can be made easily using [react-native-gifted-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-charts).

This chart library needs minimal learning and provides amzing features like animation, touchable, scroll, gradient etc.

Open [gifted charts documentation](https://gifted-charts.web.app/areachart) and scroll down to the ***pointerConfig*** section to see example charts with sliding bar and tooltip.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't support Web, yet.